# Does a matrix being not regular imply its null space is not empty?

Tags: matrices

I am trying to parse this paper. The authors at one point make use of a property that a matrix being not regular is equivalent to its null space being not empty. They don't have a reference for this claim and i was just wondering if this is something that's well known? I looked up stuff about regular matrices and the few things i looked at point to the matrix or any of its power being positive element wise. I am not quite sure how that ties to how the authors in this paper used it.

I am attaching a screenshot of the section where they used this property. Any help will be appreciated. Cheers!

[image]

Comment: My guess is that they use regular here to mean invertible

Comment: Also, they seem to be assuming tacitly that $u\neq0$.

Comment: Can you cite the paper?

Comment: You need to provide the definition of a regular matrix. Wikipedia lists 5 different definitions.

Comment: @Joe Sorry should have done that before. Here's the paper: Theoretical and Experimental Comparison of Optimisation Criteria for Downlink Beamforming

Comment: @Rushy I guess that's what they mean here. I just wanted to confirm if someone else has come across this definition of a matrix being regular in some other context

Comment: @MarkSaving exactly my point. That's what i am trying to clarify. The ones i have come across are the ones which say that a matrix or its power has entries which are all positive. But i don't see how that's related to what the authors in this paper had.